# Socket communication - if (socket.Connected) sometimes stuck false on specific IP address even after reboot

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, websocket, tcpclient

I use socket communication in a Unity mobile application. The app communicate with different devices. It works 99% of the time, but sometimes the "socket.Connected" part stuck false even, when the device is available (from other instance of the app). So the issue is local. The problem presist even after the app is restarted or even after the phone rebooted! But after some time it works again.
It only stuck with one IP address. (For example with 192.168.1.4 not works, but with 192.168.1.5 works)
So the big question is: What can cause this issue so deep, that even rebooting the phone, does not fix.

```c#
static void Thread(object cData)
{
     ConnectionData cdata = (ConnectionData)cData;
     ConnectAsync(cdata);
}

static void ConnectAsync(ConnectionData cdata)
{
     Device device = cdata.device;
     string[] messages = cdata.messages;
     Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, 
     ProtocolType.Tcp);

     try
     {
         socket.ReceiveTimeout = timeoutMs;
         socket.SendTimeout = timeoutMs;
         IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse(device.IP);
         IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAdd, device.Port);
         IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, null, null);
         result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMs);

         if (socket.Connected) // <--THE_PROBLEM = This stuck FALSE
         { 
           ...code...
         }
      }  
     ...
}
```

Comment: if using a `Thread` anyway then why use the `async` methods? You alread are on a background thread -> simply stick to the synchronous ones, way easier to read and write that way .. and then I would rather simply use a [`TcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) instead of configuring and handling the underlying socket "by hand"

Comment: Either way .. it sounds like you don't dispose the socket properly and the port might be stuck at being already in use (by your previous instance of the app)

Comment: Thank you for response! I will try a solution based on your comment.